# How many 9-digit numbers contain at least one 8?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

US social security numbers have 9 digits, and can start with 0.

There are $10^9$ possible SSNs. There are $9^9$ that do not use one digit. Thus, I know the correct answer is $10^9-9^9=612,579,511$.

How can this question be solved by counting permutations?

So far, I am thinking something similar to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112134/how-many-10-digit-phone-numbers-have-at-least-one-of-each-odd-digit), but my answer is wrong:
$(10C1)*10^8-(10C2)*10^7+(10C3)*10^6...=513,164,,800 $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to adapt that method in the other post (the principle of inclusion exclusion) is
$$
\binom{9}110^8-\binom{9}210^7+\binom{9}310^6-\cdots+\binom{9}910^0
$$
That is, choose a spot which has an $8$ in $\binom{9}1$ ways, and fill in the rest of the digits in $10^8$ ways. However, this double counts SSN's which have an $8$ in two spots, so you need to subtract $\binom{9}210^7$ to compensate, and so on. This can be proven to simplify to $10^9-9^9$, using the binomial theorem on $10^9-(10-1)^9$.

Answer (score 0):

You want to solve it permutation. Well , I will use exponential generating functions because it involves in permutations with repetition.

Firtly , let find the exponenetial generating function without restriction . It is $1+x +x^2 / 2 +.... =e^x$ . Moreover , there are $10$ different digits. Hence it is $e^{10x}$. We should find the coefficient of $\frac{x^{9}}{9!}$. We can do it by $10^{9}$.

Now ,lets find our arrangements without having any $8$ . It can be done $e^{9x}$. We should find the coefficient of $\frac{x^{9}}{9!}$. We can do it by $9^{9}$.

So , $$10^{10} - 9^9$$ ,we obtain like clssical counting

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(k)$ be the number of $k$-digit numbers that cotain at least one $8$.

Clearly, $f(1)=1$.

Also, a number can either end with an $8$ or it won't. So,
\begin{equation*}
f(k+1)=9.10^{k-1}+f(k)
\end{equation*}

This recurrence relation will take you to the answer.

In case you want a closed form, the trick to find it is [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linear-recurrence-relations/).

**A little elaboration on the recurrence-**

We are trying to find the number of ways of having a $(k+1)$-digit number with at least one $8$. If this number ends with an $8$, then the first $k$ digits can be chosen in $9.10^{k-1}$ ways. If it does not end with an $8$, the first $k$ digits have to be chosen in such a way that it contains at least one $8$, which by definition of $f$ is $f(k)$.